# Como puedo convertir campos nulos que traigo de SQL Server a un valor 0 en C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy tratando de traer en una vista mis campos, pero sucede que en **SQL** hay algunos campos nulos, y **C#** no me permite traerlos debido al siguiente error:

> "La conversión al tipo de valor '**Int32**' falló porque el valor
>   materializado es nulo. El parámetro genérico del tipo de resultado o
>   la consulta deben usar un tipo que pueda contener nulos".

Este es mi código:

```
 public List<V_DetallesReserva> LeerListadoDetalleReservaDisponibles(string estado)
    {
      try
      {
        using (BDDRestauranteEntities bd = new BDDRestauranteEntities())
        {
          return bd.V_DetallesReserva.Where(x => x.Estado == estado).ToList();
        }
      }
      catch (FormatException ex)
      {
        throw ex;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw ex;
      }
    }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias !

Comment: SQL Server tiene una funcion llamada ISNULL(Valor,ValorDeRemplazo), que reemplaza el valor NULL por uno que tu elijas. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! donde hay una conversion a entero en este codigo como para que tire ese error?

Comment: Me puedes indicar como tienes estructurada esta clase **`V_DetallesReserva`** o es una tabla ?, bueno y por si te sirve , cuando tienes campos que aceptan nulos en **SQL** y necesitas que en **C#** también los aceptes puedes agregar el símbolo **`?`** a los tipos de datos de la propiedad asi **Ej:** `public int? numeroNull {get; set;}`

Comment: V_DetalleReserva es una vista..

Comment: No tengo que reemplazar en sql los null por 0, ya que si reemplazo por null, yo no tengo Id's 0..Yo quiero convertir en c# los nulos a 0

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar. Donde este codigo hace una transformacion a enteros? y de paso, lee los enlaces que te pase porfa

Answer (score 0):

intenta agregando un select para hacer la conversión y aplicar el operador ?? al campo que se requiera asignar el cero

ejemplo:

```
bd.V_DetallesReserva.Select(x=>new {id=x.id??0,Estado=x.Estado,...}).Where(x => x.Estado == estado).ToList();
```

Comment: Me dice que el campo "id" no contiene ninguna definicion...Intente poner mi Id Mesa..Pero tampoco funciona, quise hacer asi:    return bd.V_DetallesReserva.Select(x=> new {id= x.Numero_Mesa ?? 0,Estado=x.Estado}).Where(x => x.Estado == estado).ToList(); Y me dice que  el operardor "??" no se pude aplicar a operadores del tipo int

Comment: Tu deberías modificar el nombre de los campos que te puse en el  select 
 del ejemplo ya que yo desconozco con que nombres los definiste tu modelo

Comment: en el new {id=> new {id= x.Numero_Mesa ?? 0,Estado=x.Estado} agrega los campos de V_DetallesReserva y intenta con el operador ?:

Answer (score 0):

Desde la definicion de tu clase  `V_DetallesReserva` marca tus propiedades nulleables con [Nulleable](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) para que los soporte.

```
class V_DetallesReserva 
{
    ...
    public Nullable<int> numeroNull { get; set; };
    ...
}
```

Con esto te permitirá realizar la consulta. Pero recuerda controlar tus propiedades null cuando las utilices. Altamente recomendado que lo hagas desde tu capa de datos.

```
using (BDDRestauranteEntities bd = new BDDRestauranteEntities())
    {
        var lst = bd.V_DetallesReserva.Where(x => x.Estado == estado).ToList();
        lst.foreach(dato => data.numeroNull == null ? 0 : data.numeroNull );
        return lst;
    }
```

Comment: Hola, no es una clase, es una vista..Como haria en ese caso ??

Comment: En tu código de ejemplo indicas que es a tu clase de modelo, a la misma tabla de tu base de datos. No a la vista.